# How to animate the line in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Am trying to animate the line in UWP . But unable to achieve it.

I have achieved the same using below WPF code,

```
<Line X1="10" X2="10" Y1="10" Y2="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="100,100,0,0">    
         <Line.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" To="100" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" To="100" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Line.Triggers>
    </Line>
```

Can anyone please tell me the equivalent code in UWP for the above .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should set name of line

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<Line x:Name="MyLine"
      X1="10"
      X2="10"
      Y1="10"
      Y2="10"
      Stroke="Black"
      StrokeThickness="3"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      Margin="100,100,0,0">
    <Line.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyLine"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2"
                                     EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                                     To="100"
                                     Duration="0:0:2" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyLine"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2"
                                     EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                                     To="100"
                                     Duration="0:0:2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Line.Triggers>
</Line>
```

I have named your Line, set TargetName and enabled EnableDependentAnimation. You will also have to remove `RoutedEvent="Loaded"` but the animation will be kicked off automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much! Its working perfectly. Great Answer!!

Comment: I see no reason for the EnableDependentAnimation="True". This animation can profit of being an Independent animation, which means it won't run on the UI thread, making the animation fluid. I'd even go further and say forcing it to be dependent is bad practice.

Comment: @DanyKhalife, except it won't work at all if you remove it. This is a WInRT limitation that path animation can only run on UI thread.

Comment: I've double checked what I said, and you're right. When modifying the shape, in this case stretching a line, we're no longer in the scope of independent animations. It's unfortunate though that the property needs to be set manually :/

Comment: @Jessica could you please change this code to C# in UWP code behind.?